# Page flip App for Windows Store APP for Surface , Scroll view not working properly

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, scrollview, page-flipping

We are developing a PageFlip application for our  publication's electronic edition.
we have used some thing like this (this is not exact code)

```
<FlipView>
   <FlipViewItem>
      <scrollView>
         <Image>
      </scrollView>
  </FlipViewItem>
  <FlipViewItem>
      <scrollView>
         <Image>
      </scrollView>
  </FlipViewItem>
</FlipView>
```

But the problem is, when the image is zoomed and  half of the image is not visible then, if i try to swipe to see the right part of image it  snaps back to left part.As soon as my finger leaves the screen it goes back to previous position. Does any one has an Idea why it is happening.
User should be able to flip through and Zoom in/out pages.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late response but I had the same problem.  You need to set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = "Auto"` on the `ScrollViewer`.